# One user on our domain cannot login on his original PC only

Tags: windows-7, active-directory

So a user says he went out to lunch and afterwards could not log into his PC. It just hangs whereas it actually does log in in safe mode and other accounts like my admin on the domain also can log in.

I checked the start up processes ran some utilities and later:

- System restore: Nope
- Repair startup: No dice
- Tons of scans for malware, rootkits, virus, nothing....

Nothing suspicious in the startup programs when I checked in safemode. Other than a recent Windows update in the morning, nothing unusual.

He logged in fine on another PC since we use roaming profiles with no issues.

I need to alter his permissions in AD tomorrow so I can actually check the system/event logs on that specific PC but I could use some help in pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I would remove the computer from the domain and then add it back.

Comment: I agree with @Logman, can he log onto the local machine?

Comment: If he uses roaming profiles, simply delete his user account folder from the machine when you log in. When he logs in again, it will create a new folder. I think the local user registry is corrupt.

Comment: +1 to Randolph West - though it won't create a new profile, it will copy the network profile back.  If roaming profiles were not used, then I'd rename the profile folder (so as to preserve his documents and other files) and THEN if he logged in it would recreate the profile.

Comment: Turns out logman is right....although my implementation of that didn't work. I had to add it to a temp domain and then back to the normal one to properly remove/add on again.

Comment: @logman and Desk, Great! Looks like that could be expanded into an *answer*, since it worked, and would help others.

Answer (score 0):

As noted above:

- add the profile to a temp domain
- delete the profile on the normal domain
- copy the profile back to the normal domain

**References**

- [Performing a Nonauthoritative Restore of AD DS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730683)